# After building a package, where is its zip file?

Tags: r

I have developed a very simple basic package called : **mypackage** in windows environment which contains one function

1. na2zero()

in R-Studio IDE i just did **Build --> Clean and Rebuild** resulted into below logs

```
==> Rcmd.exe INSTALL --preclean --no-multiarch --with-keep.source package

* installing to library 'C:/Users/NAME/Documents/R/R-4.0.0/library'
* installing *source* package 'mypackage' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'mypackage'
    finding HTML links ...    hello                                   html  
    na2zero                                 html  
 done
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (mypackage)
```

i'm able to invoke the functions which resides in ***mypackage***, but my question is, i want to see the location of the package, i believe the extension will be .zip

so in which folder the package (mypackage) exists.?

Comment: That should be the folder containing the package/project folder. The latter you can find by looking in RStudio's *Files*  panel.

Comment: but you should rather use *Build [Source/Binary] Package*.

Comment: @Roland thank you, it worked for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In RStudio, the "Install and Restart" menu item in the Build pane will install the package directly into R, without creating an archive file.

If you want to create an archive, there are two kinds of those.  Use "Build Source Package" (in the "More..." menu) to create a `.tar.gz` file, which can be installed in any current version of R, and also some past and future ones, on any supported platform.

Use "Build Binary Package" to create a binary package.  On Windows, that would be a `.zip` file.  It is only good for Windows and a very small range of R versions (typically if you build in R version X.Y.Z, you'll be able to use it for different value of Z, but not different values of X or Y).  You won't be able to use it on Linux or MacOS.

For a simple package, you should almost always use the "Source Package" format.  Only when you have compiled code (C, C++, Fortran) is it a good idea to use the "Binary Package" format:  your users may not have the compiler needed to install it themselves.  But you'll need to match your users' R versions very carefully.

For both Source and Binary packages, RStudio will put the archive file in the same folder as your package source is in, e.g. if your package version 1.0.0 is in
`path/to/mypackage`, it will produce `path/to/mypackage_1.0.0.zip`.